# Database schema design implementation feedback

Tags: database-design, schema

I'm having difficulty on designing a database schema design with the right relationships. I'm currently trying to design a database system where a `question` can be answer via a  `live_stream`. The general idea is that a `user` can ask a `question`. Then a `user` can `answer` the question and set a `live_stream`. Many `users` can join that `live_stream`. Here is the diagram. https://dbdiagram.io/d/5f2a06ce7543d301bf5de918

[image]

I have added a link to the schema design where you can navigate the relationships. But basically the idea is as follows.

- A user can create many questions. `user` 1 -> * `question`
- A question belongs to a user
- A user can like a question `user` 1 -> * `likes`,
- A question can have many likes by users. `question` 1 -> * `likes`
- A question has one answer `question` 1 -> 1 `answer`
- and an answer belongs to a user `user` 1 -> `answer`

Here is something I have struggle with. Basically I have created a join table for a many to many relationship between `users` and `answers`. Using `live_streams` as the join table. The way I see it is that many `users` can watch the explanation of the live_stream for the `answer` and the `answer` can have many users watch the `live_stream`. Also I added `presenter` to the `live_streams` table. The `presenter` is also a `user`.

- Many users can join a live stream `users` 1 -> * `live_streams`
- A live stream belongs to an answer `answers` 1 -> * `live_streams`
- A user is a presenter of the live stream `user` 1 -> 1 `live_stream`

I'm still a but skeptical about the way `live_streams` table works as a join table between `users` and `answers`. Is still clear to me that many users can join a live stream. but not sure if the relationship between `answers` and `live_streams` should be a one to many, but I see it as `live_stream` belongs to `answer`.

The user presenting the live stream has to be the person who answered the question. So if the `answer` belongs to a `user`, that same `user` should be the `presenter` in the `live_streams` table. The `answers` table works more as setting the time, description and name of when the live stream is going to take place.

Is this correct? I'm open to feedback as to how to improve the design or if there is any errors in the logic.

Comment: Does the user presenting the live stream have to be the person who answered it? And are we sure each question will have at most one answer, or is it one *accepted* answer.

Comment: @bbaird correct the user presenting the live stream has to be the person who answered it. Answer is more of a conceptual thing, which means the user that creates an answer is going to do the live stream.

Comment: For your second question `And are we sure each question will have at most one answer, or is it one accepted answer. ` I was thinking it would be easier at first to just have one answer.

Comment: Okay, I think I know what you are doing.  Are you limited by a ORM that is really bad with composite (multi-part ) keys?

Comment: I will be dealing with a ORM, but honestly, I haven't design a system in a while so my implementation might have some errors.

Comment: @bbaird I think I can use multi-part keys

Comment: Can a user answer or vote on their own question, or would you want the ability to prevent this?

Comment: @bbaird that's a great question, yes user can answer and vote their own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, given there are no restrictions on the behavior of someone asking a question, we can forgo a lot of trouble migrating the `UserId` through the data model.

I don't think you're too far from the mark, just some unnecessary `Id` columns that aren't providing value.

This should satisfy the requirements as you've described them:

[image]

Some notes:

1. I changed `Like` to `Vote` since that gives more flexibility.
2. If we do need to restrict the behavior of the person asking the question, we would need to use their `UserId` in the primary key, or change the primary key from `QuestionId` to something like `(UserId,AskDatetime)` or (`UserId`,`QuestionNumber)`.
3. If you do choose to allow more than one answer per question, you would change the primary key of `Answer` to `(QuestionId,UserId)` (although you might want to rename `UserId` to something like `AnswererUserId`).  To denote an answer as accepted, you'd need to create an `AcceptedAnswer` table where `QuestionId` is the primary key and `AcceptedAnswer` would have the relation to `LiveStream`.
4. The one 'oopsie' that could occur with this data model is logging that the presenter (the person who answered the question) also attended their own Livestream.  If you were doing attendee counts, you'd need to query `Answer` to make sure you don't count them.  If that is very mission critical, you'd move the `UserId` of the answerer to the primary key of `Answer` and migrate that through `LiveStream` to `LiveStreamAttendee` and place a check constraint to ensure the `UserId` of the attendee is not the `UserId` of the answerer.